# Recover true statistics for a union of subsamples - only data available are summary statistics for each subsample

Tags: statistics

Let $a_1$, $a_2$, ...,$a_m$ be the samples of data, and let us further assume the only information we have about each sample is their *count/no. of samples*, *mean*, *standard deviation* and *median*.

The task I have set myself is to recover the true, or at least the best estimate possible, of the *mean*, *median* and *standard deviation* of the  union of these samples $a_1 \cup a_2 \cup ... \cup a_m$, which I will call $A$.

**Recover the Mean**

Recovering the mean is straightforward as we can just use the number of samples to recover the mean for $A$.

$$\bar{x}_1 = \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n_1} x_i, \quad  \bar{x}_2 = \frac{1}{n_2} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n_2} x_i \quad  ... \quad$\bar{x}_m = \frac{1}{n_m} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n_m} x_i$$

$$ \bar{x}_A = \frac{n_1\bar{x}_1 + n_2\bar{x}_2 + ... + n_m\bar{x}_m}{n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_m} $$

**Recover the Standard Deviation**

This seems like it should be possible.

The standard deviation of a particular sample is defined as:
$$ s_i = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n_i} (x_k - \bar{x}_i)^2}{n_i-1}}$$

It seems to me, we could do the following to attempt to recover the *standard deviation* of $A$. Essentially we could assume a symmetric deviation about the subsample mean for each data point, half below, half above, and calculate the new whole sample standard deviation using the difference between the whole sample mean $\bar{x}_A$ and each subsample mean $\bar{x}_i$.

For a particular sample, say $a_i$, let us assume one-half of the data points are below the sample mean, and one-half are above the sample mean.

Because we can recover the sample $A$ mean from the data, we can use this new calculate the difference between the sample $A$'s mean and the subsample mean. This can then be used to attempt a recovery of the sample $A$'s standard deviation.

Let $d_i$ be the difference of a particular subsample from the overall sample mean $\bar{x}_A$, and let $s_i$ be the subsample standard deviation. Then

$$
s_A = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}n_1(d_1 + s_1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_1(d_1 - s_1)^2 \\+ \frac{1}{2}n_2(d_2 + s_2)^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_2(d_2 - s_2)^2 \\+ ... + \frac{1}{2}n_m(d_m + s_m)^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_m(d_m - s_m)^2}{n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_m - 1}}
$$

**Recover the Median**

I see no straightforward way for this to be accurate. We do have an idea of the dispersion and the difference between the mean and the median for each sample so I do have glimmers of possibilities but I have not thought deeply or can see a very obvious path.

**My Question**

Can anyone comment on these strategies, offer their expertise, or point me to some resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The more general way to look at the problem is to understand the concept of moments. The raw moments are simple statistics and easy to aggregate, where mean is average of the first moment, count is sum of the zeroth moment. Standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis, etc can all be constructed from these moments.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)
Median, however, is order statisics, and if you are restricted to use a small constant representation like what you are right now, there only exists approximate algorithms for order statistics except for Min and Max.

Comment: And what would be the way to recover the median if I can choose any form of the representation of the groups?

Answer (score 0):

For the standard deviation:  I'd just use brute force.  You want to compute $\sum (z_i-\mu)^2$ where the z's cover the union and $\mu$ is the new mean.  Splitting the sum over your two variables X and Y we see that we just need to compute $\sum {x_i}^2, \sum {x_i}, \sum {y_i}^2, \sum {y_i}$ but these sums are all easily computed from the data attached to the initial samples.

Not sure about the median.  I doubt it is recoverable.